# I tried to join two arrays arr[5] and brr[5] s.t. the elements of "brr" are placed just after "arr"...compiled successfully but doesn't run

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

main()

{

int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

int brr[5]={6,7,8,9,10};

int *p,*m;

m=&brr[0];

p=&arr[4];

int count=5;

while(count!=0)

    {
    p++;
    *p=*m;
    m++;
    count--;
    }

p=&arr[0];

while(count<=9)

   {

    printf("%d ",*p);
    p++;
    count++;
   }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're trying to write into memory you don't own.

Comment: Amazingly, your code runs on my system, **but it should not**.

Comment: It runs by luck- the two arrays are declared one after another, making them into one contiguous memory block. Which is why it "runs". But yeah, **it should not**

Comment: @meagar how do i own the memory locations just after array "arr" ?

Comment: @r2b, By making the array bigger? You gain ownership of memory either by declaring it on the stack or calling `malloc` to grab some from the heap.

Comment: @merlin2011  malloc() assigns memory locations randomly, isn't it??

Comment: No, it does not. It has an algorithm and a policy for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write past the end of the array `arr`, which has undefined behavior.

Instead, you should allocate an array with enough space for the combination of the two arrays, and then write into that instead.

```
int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

Also, note that `memcpy` already does what you want, although I assume this is only an exercise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int brr[5]={6,7,8,9,10};
    memcpy(arr + 5, brr, 5*sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You réserve only 5 ints in `arr` and write 10. C does no size control in arrays and your code compiles fine. But at runtime, you will overwrite unwanted memory locations. You should have

```
int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

to reserve enough memory.

Comment: thanks a lot!! could not upvote because i am new here.